# Create a combo box from the values of a textbox that will change every time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input name="textbox2" id="edValue" type="text" onInput="edValueKeyPress()"><br>
      <input name="textbox3" id="textbox3"  ><br>
      <p/>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function edValueKeyPress() {
       var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
       var s = edValue.value;
       textbox3.value=s.concat('world');;
      }    
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var data = {  'Country1': 'Sri Lanka', 'Country2': 'USA', 'Country3': 'Australia', 'Country4': 'Newzeland'};

          var s = $('<select id="combo" />');

          for(var val in data) {
              $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
          }
          s.appendTo('p');    

          //when we select an item from dropdown or combobox then alert that value
          $(document).on('change',"#combo", function(){
              alert(this.value);
          });
      });

   </script>
</html>
```

I want to populate a combobox like below,on every change of values in the textbox3,that will change every time with textbox2

```
<select id="combo">
    <option value="Country1">Sri Lanka (value from textbox3) </option>
    <option value="Country2">USA (value from textbox3) </option>
    <option value="Country3">Australia (value from textbox3)</option>
    <option value="Country4">Newzeland (value from textbox3)</option>
</select>
```

that means every time combo box value should change with text box value.

Right now only changes only affecting in the textbox3 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
  var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
  var s = edValue.value;
  textbox3.value = s.concat('world');
  var getValueTextbox = document.getElementById("textbox3").value;
  make_combobox(getValueTextbox);
}

make_combobox('');

function make_combobox(textbox) {
  $('#combo').remove();
  var data = {
    'Country1': 'Sri Lanka',
    'Country2': 'USA',
    'Country3': 'Australia',
    'Country4': 'Newzeland'
  };

  var s = $('<select id="combo" />');

  for (var val in data) {
    $('<option />', {
      value: val,
      text: data[val] + '=>' + textbox
    }).appendTo(s);
  }
  s.appendTo('p');

  //when we select an item from dropdown or combobox then alert that value
  $(document).on('change', "#combo", function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="textbox2" id="edValue" type="text" onInput="edValueKeyPress()"><br>
<input name="textbox3" id="textbox3"><br>
<p/>
```

Comment: This doesn't creates a combobox. Also, after writing a few letters in the first input alert works as insane.

Comment: @vadivel a Thanks, this is what I need

Comment: Feedback: supplying code in an answer is helpful. However, what (future) readers really appreciate is accompanying text to describe what the code does. Information about what it does or why it is an answer to the question can be very useful.